# Using VBA to link spreadsheet that has data

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I am trying to use VBA to point at criteria in a spreadsheet. I would just like to point the code at a spreadsheet to pull the criteria rather than constantly having to update the code for new criteria.

```
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 1 Step -1
    If (Cells(i, "D").Value) <> 0 And (Cells(i, "A").Value) Like "*00000*" Then
        Cells(i, "N") = "'000"
    ElseIf (Cells(i, "A").Value) Like "002000*" Then
        Cells(i, "N") = "211"
    End If
```

I would just like to make it so that I can just update the spreadsheet with new criteria and have the code recognize it automatically.

Comment: Which criteria? `*00000*` and `*002000*`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Dim crit1, crit2

crit1 = Sheets("Criteria").Range("A1").value '*00000*
crit2 = Sheets("Criteria").Range("A2").value '002000*

If (Cells(i, "D").Value) <> 0 And (Cells(i, "A").Value) Like crit1 Then
    Cells(i, "N") = "'000"
ElseIf (Cells(i, "A").Value) Like crit2 Then
    Cells(i, "N") = "211"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have to expand on it. What I am doing is pulling a certain criteria from data dumped from our software (1st criteria). The second criteria (000, 211) is coming from columns in a second spreadsheet tab. I want to be able to reference the column in the other spreadsheet and pull the right data based on the first criteria.

Comment: So how are they all related?  If you had to do this manually exactly how would you find the relevant values?

Comment: bascially the "00000"  and "002000" are departments from our old system and the second values are "000" and "211" are departments from the new system.